# Launch configurations not appearing anymore after Eclipse update with Quarkus

Tags: eclipse, quarkus, m2eclipse

I'm using Quarkus 3.5.3, and we had a couple of problems with Eclipse after the update. So I installed Eclipse 2023-12 and added the Quarkus Tools (4.29.0.Final, no newer version was offered by the Eclipse Marketplace).

Now however, my launch configurations for building with Maven (m2 plugin) don't appear anymore. I mean, I can right-click on a `.launch` file and launch it with `Run As`. But if I right-click on the project and choose `Run As`, the launch configurations don't appear. To be more precise, I just get `Maven build...`, as if I didn't have any m2 launch configurations.
The same goes for the keyboard shortcut `Shift+Alt+X`: If I choose `M` (for Maven), nothing happens.

Not being able to use the keyboard shortcut means a lot of work over time :-)

It was still working with Eclipse 2023-06 (and still is for my JEE Eclipse). So, does anyone have an idea? Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug?

Thanks for any information...

Here's a screenshot - I do see my successfully started m2 launch configurations (starting with number 9). Still no `Maven build` though.

[image: Run As]

Comment: Do you talk about Maven launch configurations only or didn't you verify that what is said in the title of your question applies to all kind of launch configurations? Can you create a new launch configurations via _Run > Run Configurations..._? If not, at which step it fails? What happen when you use a fresh workspace (_File > Switch Workspace > Other..._ without copying any settings)?

Comment: I meant only Maven launch configurations. But because of your question I also tried some Java Application launch configuration. It doesn't show either.
Using `Run > Run Configurations...` I was able to create a new Maven launch configuration and run it. But it still doesn't appear (see new screenshot above).
Then I created a new workspace and imported the project. Same result: Launch configurations don't appear.